# Help Me Find a Matching Font for My Logo

Tags: website-design, fonts, logo, font-recommendation

I have designed the logo below for a social network and am looking to put the name "UMMATI" beside it. I'm trying to decide on a font that looks good beside it and to decide whether the text should be in all caps or not.

Being a social network logo, the text doesn't have to be too serious. It should be fun and perhaps even a little playful but maybe that's going to far.

At first I was thinking about a really heavy font weight but that did not look right. I suspect that I should be choosing a font whose lines are as thick as the lines in the logo which makes it a relatively light weight.

In terms of colour, the colours of the logo below are not final but I'm considering blue or green as the primary colour. In terms of the text, I'm thinking black but lack imagination.

I'd really appreciate some tips or suggestions!

[image: Ummati Logo]

Comment: I see an "S" and an "M" with two "i's" looking at me and an "o." Is this intended for any relevance or significance?

Comment: It's a style of Arabic called square kufic which seems built for logos and the web: https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-arabic-calligraphy-square-kufic--cms-23012

Answer (score 2):

*The lack of relevant important data in your question, such as **what type of company the logo is intended**, put the only valid answers around visually graphic results, essentially unsustainable (text before the question update).*

Usually making a logo design comes together with the text name. In your case there is only a graphic result, you have to find an element of big importance to **integrate** without seeming a patch. In fact, choosing a catalog type can lead to the omission of relevant visual elements in the text, that could have been present from the beginning, such as:

- A simple six characters word
- The **MM** repetition
- Start and end with a vowel
- Characters practically without curved strokes

In this situation, using **design contrast** as a starting point can be helpful, or at list you can choose what kind of relation you search between the image and the name. Here some examples (excepting Color Contrast individually because is included in all of them)*

### Harmony

The contrast is understood taking as a starting point the harmony, in this case, shape harmony.

```
Font 404PX
```

[image: HARMONY]

### Style Contrast

```
Font Microsoft Himalaya
```

[image: STYLE]

### Shape Contrast

```
Font Circular Abstracts
```

[image: Shape]

### Weight Contrast

```
Font House 3009 Black
```

[image: Weight]

### Space Contrast

```
Font Modular Serif Bold
```

[image: Space]

### Texture Contrast

Actually the image is like a labyrinth, the font can follow this labyrinth in some way.

```
Font Industria Solid
```

[image: TEXTURE]

### Size Contrast

```
Font House 3009 Bold
```

[image: Size]

### Direction Contrast

```
Font Modula Round Sans Regular
```

[image: Direction]

*With variations in names, there is a lot of information in internet about design contrast.

Comment: These are some really great ideas. I've updated my question. The logo is for a social network.

Comment: "Ummati, ummati" - the last words spoken by Mohammed. In Arabic it means "My people, my people".  *Ummah* - nation/people/the Muslim worldwide community.

Comment: @Danielillo What font did you use for the text under "Size Contrast"?

Comment: Answer updated with the font names